# X-mirror pose isn't symmetrical

Tags: rigging, eevee-render-engine

After I rigged my model, every part of the rig was working perfectly and symmetrical, except for the parts of the eyes.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the bones staying symmetrical, but the mesh is not following them symmetrically, or are not even the bones mirroring eachother? Have not checked the file yet. BTW, for future reference, use blend-exchange.com for blend files on this site.

Comment: That file is locked anyway so can't be downloaded without a google account.

Comment: TheLabCat, the bones are aligned correctly to the mesh, but the problem is maybe the weights. I just used automatic weights and used the "Rigify" addon.

Answer (score 2):

Bones **lid.T.L** and **lid.T.R** are placed exactly at mirrored position -0.14287 / 0.14287 ...

... but your mesh vertices (pink oval) aren't and also vertex assignments to bones and weight is different (pink rectangle).

[image]

[image]

It means bones are mirrored correctly, but vertices translation can't result mirrored in this condition right ... I'm sure it is not an issue just of the eyes, but whole model. The shift is just more noticeable at eyeballs since there just a small difference at position radically penetrates eyeball surface.